# Loading GIPHY Images into table view

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, animated-gif

Hey everyone so I am trying to load all of the gif images from the GIPHY API but I keep getting the error below.

```
2022-06-09 10:39:12.255202-0700 GIPHY App[41186:1667340] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(153) Failed to log metrics
2022-06-09 10:39:12.356240-0700 GIPHY App[41186:1667113] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__SwiftValue 0x600001ec5020> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key url.'
```

Below is my code that I have written to try and load the images into the table view using alamofire and alamofireimages.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import AlamofireImage

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    
    var giphyImage = [GiphyData]()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var giphyTableView: UITableView!
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        fetchGiphyData()

    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return giphyImage.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! GiphyTableViewCell
        
        let gif: GiphyData
        gif = giphyImage[indexPath.row]
        
        AF.request(gif.url).responseImage { response in
            if let image = response.value {
                cell.giphyImage.image = image
            }
        
                if case .success(let image) = response.result {
                    print("image downloaded: \(image)")
                }
        }
        return cell
    }
    
    func fetchGiphyData() {
    
        let request = AF.request("https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/trending?api_key=zONZGFIbbvYDBjLEBlgKxLjbsClfmptw&limit=25&rating=pg-13")
        
        request.responseDecodable(of: GiphyResponseData.self) { (response) in
            guard let gifs = response.value else { return }
            
            let gifImages = [gifs]
            
            for i in 0..<gifImages.count {
                
                self.giphyImage.append(GiphyData(
                    url: ((gifImages[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "url") as! String)
                ))
            }
            self.giphyTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

I am looking to grab the urls from the GiphyData struct when I am parsing the JSON info but maybe thats incorrect? I am new to attempting projects on my own so any advice/ help is awesome!

```
import UIKit

struct GiphyResponseData: Codable {
    var data: [ImageInfo]
}

struct ImageInfo: Codable {
    var images: ImageTypes
}

struct ImageTypes: Codable {
    var original: GiphyData
}

struct GiphyData: Codable {
    var url: String
}
```

Can anyone tell me why the error keeps popping up? I am getting the urls that i need from the fetchGiphyData function but the table view isnt loading the images.

Comment: Is that `(gifImages[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "url")` the line causing the issue? Why do you write `let gifImages = [gifs]`? It's not making any sense. The loop, should be instead: `for anImageInfo in gifs { let aGiphyData = anImageData.images.orignal; self.giphyImage.append(aGiphyData) }`

Comment: @Larme yes thats where the error is coming from but in your code you have aGiphyData = anImageData did you mean to access gifs.data?

Comment: @Larme I see what you're doing and what you mean now. I am just having a difficult time trying to figure out how to access the url data that is nested 4 layers deep within the json info